# ImageUrl is not changing on dynamic added Image

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate, imageurl

I am adding a set of images on Page_Init, and on some button click I want to update those images. For some reason it doesn't work. why?

This is my code:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++)
        {
            TableRow newTableRow = new TableRow();
            TableTestAnswers.Rows.Add(newTableRow);
            TableCell questionNumberCell = new TableCell();
            newTableRow.Cells.Add(questionNumberCell);
            LinkButton questionNumberLinkButton = new LinkButton();
            questionNumberCell.Controls.Add(questionNumberLinkButton);
            questionNumberLinkButton.Text = ((char)(i + 'A')).ToString();           

            TableCell answersCell = new TableCell();
            newTableRow.Cells.Add(answersCell);
            answersCell.ID = "AnswersCell-" + i.ToString();

            for (int j = 0; j < answersCount[i]; j++)
            {
                Image answerImage = new Image();
                answersCell.Controls.Add(answerImage);
                answerImage.ID = "Answer-" + i.ToString() + "-" + j.ToString();
                answerImage.ImageUrl = Resources.Images.AnswerEmptySquareUrl;
            }

    protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...        
        Image answerImage = (Image)TableTestAnswers.FindControl(
             "Answer-" + questionIndex.ToString() + "-" + answerIndex.ToString());
        answerImage.ImageUrl = Resources.Images.AnswerMarkedUrl;
        answerImage.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;
    }
```

I can see that ButtonSubmit finds the correct control and changes its property, but on the response to the client I still see the old image. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this is a case of image caching, i.e. Are the file names for the new images the same as the file names for the old images?